# forbidden paths in a graph

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm

We are provided with a directed graph (data flow graph). We want to forbid the data from reaching some nodes of the graph, which means we will have forbidden paths to delete but must keep the graph connected.

I propose a simple example to make the problem clear:

Let us have the following graph:

A ------>B-------->C-------->D

I want to forbid data from reaching the node C, so the edge B-C will be removed. At the same time I want the data to reach D. So a new edge from B-D will be created.

Is there an efficient algorithm for the above task?

Thank you.

Comment: can you just remove all the unwanted node, and if the graph is disconnected, add an edge from data source to data sink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every node X that is not allowed to be reached has i incoming edges and j outgoing edges. As we talk about a data-flow graph it is not sufficient for a node before X to only reach one of the j nodes after X. Either you can insert a dummy (Steiner) node X' that has no function except for not being labeled X where you send all i edges and also connect the j outgoing edges. Otherwise you might have to connect every node where one of the i incoming edges originates and connect it to all j nodes where the outgoing edges of X lead. (Otherwise the data flow is broken.)

To repair one to one node is a constant time operation, but repairing all relations for one such node X takes O(i*j) time, i.e., it is quadratic in the number of incident edges.

[image: Data from a,b, and c flows to X and from there to either x,y, or]

Data from a,b, and c flows to X and from there to either x,y, or z.

[image: Thus, data from a can reach x,y, and z.]

Thus, data from a can reach x,y, and z.

[image: To remove the edge from a->x we have to add edges from a to all nodes that are reachable from X.]

To remove the edge from a->X we have to add edges from a to all nodes that are reachable from X. Since we have to do this for every edge that reaches X we get a quadratic complexity.

EDIT: (Due to the comment) For two forbidden nodes X and Y were there is an edge form X to Y, such an edge can stay. After all edges to all forbidden nodes (except from a forbidden node) are removed the forbidden nodes may form connected components of size > 1. This is not a problem as every such connected component contains only forbidden nodes and edges and can not be reached from the remaining flow-graph.

After this, we only remove edges that lead from a valid node to a forbidden node. These edges have to be removed in order to fulfil the demand. No other edge is removed, thus this is the minimum amount that fulfils the request. (I don't think there is much else to prove here.)

Comment: Thank's gue 

So basically, the algorithme is the following : 

1-  Search for all paths between the source and the node X. 
2-  Save the neighbours of X is a set A 
3-  Save the nodes that are in the path and have X as a neighbour in a set B. 
4-  Remove egdes from nodes of the set B and X. 
5-  Add edges from nodes in set B to the nodes in set A . 

if it's correct ...what's the complexity of this algorithm ?

Comment: For 1, if by source you mean the nodes that have a direct edge leading to X, then yes. And depending on how your graph is stored this should be constant time to reach a neighbour of X. All paths that pass through X must go through a node that has an edge that ends at X, so only those are needed. As your condition is that X is not to be reached, only edge that end at X have to be removed, edges the lead away from X should be fine. Complexity is mentioned in the post, for i incoming and j outgoing edges the complexity takes O(i*j) time for every such node X.

Comment: thank's again for the example, i have one more question, how to prove that by using this method i have deleted the minimum of edges possible ?

Comment: @gue...thank's for the update ...but what I wanted to say is ..is that algorithm optimal ? how to prove it ?

Comment: @StambouliA.ouadoud One could proof it by categorising the edges. Every Edge e goes from a node A to a node B. Now A could be forbidden or B or both or none. Now we can look at every type in detail and verify that this approach removes all the right edges. The optimality could maybe be shown by a proof by contradiction: Assuming we would get an optimal result by letting one of the removed edges stay. Then one could show that this edge goes to a forbidden node and that the algorithm is then not valid.